# Filtering Pandas Dataframe Records, based on "key:value" match in a list of dictionaries as 2nd field of the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like below in a pandas dataframe. What I want is to check the values in second column, which look like a list of dictionaries, and keep only those full records for which `platform` is `Windows` and `script_type` is `PowerShell`

Is there a way to do it only using Dataframe concept, instead of using a for loop method to iterate across the list of dictionaries for each of the fields in the 2nd column.

The first column is named `Names`, and the second column is `Data`

````
script1   [{'platform': 'Windows','script': 'script1 code for Windows','script_type': 'PowerShell'},{'platform': 'Linux','script': 'script1 code for Linux','script_type': 'UnixShell'}]
script2   [{'platform': 'Windows','script': 'script2 code for Windows','script_type': 'PowerShell'},{'platform': 'Linux','script': 'script2 code for Linux','script_type': 'UnixShell'}]
script3   [{'platform': 'Windows','script': 'script3 code for Windows','script_type': 'VBScript'}]
script4   [{'platform': 'Linux','script': 'script4 code for Linux','script_type': 'UnixShell'}]
script5   [{'platform': 'Windows','script': 'script5 code for Windows','script_type': 'PowerShell'},{'platform': 'Linux','script': 'script5 code for Linux','script_type': 'UnixShell'}]
script6   [{'platform': 'AIX','script': 'script6 code for AIX','script_type': 'UnixShell'},{'platform': 'Linux','script': 'script6 code for Linux','script_type': 'UnixShell'}]```
````

Answer (score 0):

Given the nested nature of your Data, you need to loop. You can use a list comprehension:

```
df['Data'] = [[d for d in l if
               d.get('platform') == 'Windows' and
               d.get('script_type') == 'PowerShell']
              for l in df['Data']]
```

You can achieve this in pure pandas by combining [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), a filter, and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html), but this won't be faster than a loop:

```
df['Data'] = (df['Data'].explode()
 .loc[lambda s: s.str['platform'].eq('Windows')
      & s.str['script_type'].eq('PowerShell')
     ]
 .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
     Names                                                                                          Data
0  script1  [{'platform': 'Windows', 'script': 'script1 code for Windows', 'script_type': 'PowerShell'}]
1  script2  [{'platform': 'Windows', 'script': 'script2 code for Windows', 'script_type': 'PowerShell'}]
2  script3                                                                                            []
3  script4                                                                                            []
4  script5  [{'platform': 'Windows', 'script': 'script5 code for Windows', 'script_type': 'PowerShell'}]
5  script6                                                                                            []
```

Comment: Your list comprehension example shows a `float object is not iterable` error.

The one with `pandas` works

Comment: @dig_123 you probably have a NaN instead of a list somewhere, you can test for that if needed by changing to `[[…] if pd.notna(l) else float('nan') for l in df['Data']]` (please provide an example)

Comment: Ideally [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77531227/edit) your question with a DataFrame constructor (or a dictionary of your data, which you can obtain with `df.to_dict('list')`).